# Ember Ajax Calls running in serial

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, parallel-processing, ember.js, routes

**Setup:**

- blah is my ember app
- find essentially calls Ember.$.ajax(url, params, method)
- the find method isn't a blocking call
- Neither of the routes nor controllers have dependencies (needs) on each other

**Problem:**

- I'm trying to figure out why the setupController (I tried activate as well) in ApplicationRoute isn't being execute until after my ajax call returns from my CowRoutes model.

[image: Cow blocking meta and user]

**Thing's I've Tried:**

- If I move the code from the setupController into the model of CowRoute they all run in parallel (they don't belong here at all, especially since they are header footer and I might hit a different route beside CowRoute).
- I tried using Ember.RSVP.resolve on my find method, everything still works, it's just still running in serial

**ApplicationRoute**

```
blah.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    // setupController runs If a route handler's context changes
    setupController: function () {
    this.controllerFor('meta_property').set('model', blah.MetaProperty.find('meta_property'));
    this.controllerFor('header').set('model', blah.User.find("user"));
    }
```

**CowRoute**

```
blah.CowRoute = blah.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
    //this.controllerFor('meta_property').set('model', blah.MetaProperty.find('meta_property'));
    //this.controllerFor('header').set('model', blah.User.find("user"));
    return blah.Cow.find('cow', params);
    //return Ember.RSVP.resolve(blah.Cow.find('cow', params));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Ember tries to `execute all model hooks of all Routes available af first`. It waits for the model hooks to finish `before executing all setupController hooks`.

**Why could this make sense?**

Let's have a look at the interface of setupController:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
...
}
```

Ember is passing the model it retrieved via the model hook into the setupController hook. This is why it has to wait.

**But why does it wait for your CowRoutes model hook before running setupController on your ApplicationRoute?**

I guess this is because, you might call `controllerFor(name)` inside setupController and Ember wants all models "to be in place".

**But i think this behaviour should not hurt too much, since the model hook is just executed when the App is entered via URL for deserialization of parameters.**

**Note:** This answer is just a guess from my side, but it seems to make sense to me. At least it should be in the right direction :-)

Comment: I was beginning to think it was something along those lines.  I wonder if I create routes specifically for the two rendered segments {{ partial 'header' }} and {{ partial 'meta_property' }} and setup routes for them and specify the model as the models mentioned in the application controller if they would be launched in the beginning... well I'm not at work until Monday.  I may have to remote in and try it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Although, now that I'm sitting here thinking, I wonder if the model hook for those two routes will actually be called since they aren't the route for the URL entered.

Answer (score 1):

According to convention, If you have a model that is not in the url and across multiple routes, its ideal to put those in the application route ;)

Comment: What do you mean put them in the application route?  I'm setting up the model's in the application route, but I think you are saying something else.